# SQL Query Design - Sum/Count only if an action happened before another action in a set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design

I have two sets:

SET 1 (sample data):

```
actionid | actiontime
---------+---------------------
123      | 2018-10-02 00:01:00
456      | 2018-10-02 00:10:00
```

SET 2 (sample data):

```
actionid | actionsteps | actionsteptime      | outputnumber
---------+-------------+---------------------+---------------
123      |  step a     | 2018-10-02 00:02:00 |    1
123      |  step b     | 2018-10-02 00:03:00 |    NULL
123      |  step a     | 2018-10-02 00:04:00 |    2
123      |  step c     | 2018-10-02 00:05:00 |    NULL
123      |  step a     | 2018-10-02 00:06:00 |    1
456      |  step a     | 2018-10-02 00:11:00 |    4
456      |  step a     | 2018-10-02 00:12:00 |    5
456      |  step b     | 2018-10-02 00:13:00 |    NULL
456      |  step a     | 2018-10-02 00:12:00 |    7
```

The possible values for actionsteps in SET 2 are "step a" or "step b" or "step c".

Only "step a" in SET 2 will have an outputnumber.

I need to calculate and SUM and COUNT of outputnumber for each actionid but the condition is only for values of "step a" which has actionsteptime less than the first actionsteptime of "step b" (which means if there is any "step b" in SET 2 for an actionid then ignore that and any actionsteps after that while calculating SUM & COUNT). If there is no "step b" for an actionid then it means it is a normal SUM & COUNT. Rows with "step c" do not impact the SUM & COUNT calculation.

So the expected output in this case is

```
actionid | count| sum
---------+---------------------
123      | 1    |  1
456      | 2    |  9
```

I am scratching my head on the right JOIN & Analytic function to use. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions to calculate the action step time for "b"s.  The rest is just filtering and aggregation:

```
select actionid, count(*), sum(outputnumber)
from (select s2.*, max(case when s2.actionstep = 'step b' then s2.actionsteptime end) over (partition by s2.actionid) as b_ast
      from set2 s2
     ) s2
where actionstep < b_ast or b_ast is null
group by actionid;
```

Comment: Did you mean actionsteptime < b_ast or b_ast is null ? Also, I have updated the question, I am not sure whether this query will work in the updated scenario. Could you take a look again? TIA

Comment: Thanks, I was able to make minor modifications to the query you proposed to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT temp.actionid, temp.actionsteps, SUM(outputnumber) sum_outputnumber, COUNT(outputnumber) count_outputnnumber FROM temp 
JOIN (SELECT temp.actionid, COUNT(outputnumber) count_outputnumber FROM temp 
GROUP BY actionid ) a 
ON a.actionid=temp.actionid 
GROUP BY temp.actionid, temp.actoinsteps
HAVING SUM(outputnumber) IS NOT NULL
```